# How Do I Handle Errors Globally in TestCafe

Tags: typescript, testing, error-handling, try-catch, testcafe

I've built up a Page Object Model for my TestCafe project in typescript. I'm finding the repetitive nature of try/catch in every method to be overkill. I always want the errors to be logged with winston.

Is there a suggested way to handle errors globally? Here's an example page:

```
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";
import logger from 'logger';

export default class DocumentQueryPage {
    path: string;
    queryDocumentsButton: Selector;

    constructor() {
        this.path = "#/records/query";

        this.queryDocumentsButton = Selector('button.btn-request-records');
    }

    async go(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await t.navigateTo(this.path)
        }
        catch (err) {
            logger.error(err)
        }
    }

    async selectFirstQuery(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await t.navigateTo(this.path)
        }
        catch (err) {
            logger.error(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise against using the try/catch block with testcafe built-in actions. You can implement your own reporter or modify the existing one instead. Please refer the following article: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/
 
It can be also useful to learn how existing reporters work. Please see how default testcafe-reporter displays errors: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-reporter-spec/blob/fac1fa6d2bfae5e51cd076f990abb6d889ee9747/src/index.js#L87
 
You can modify an existing reporter by adding your own error handling logic to the `reportTestDone` method.